# How to insert the data if the image field is empty using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying the data like title,Description and image.If i give only title and description without adding image the data should be inserted into database.But if I am trying that getting error.Here is my error and code:

> **error: error while uploading**

my code

```
$title=$_POST['blog_title'];
$result = str_replace(" ", "-", $title);
$description=$_POST['blog_description'];
$name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
$type=$_FILES["image"]["type"];
$size=$_FILES["image"]["size"];
$temp=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$error=$_FILES["image"]["error"];
if($error>0)
die("error while uploading");
else
{
if($type == "image/png" || $type == "image/jpg"|| $type == "image/jpeg" || $type == "image/svg" || $type == "image/jpe" )
{
move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name);
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(image,blog_title,blog_description)values('$name','$result','$description')");
echo "upload complete";
session_start();
header("Location:blogimage.php");   
}
else
{
echo "failure";
}
```

Html Code

```
<form method="POST" action="blogs.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="blog_title" value="">
</div>
<div>
<label for="image">IMAGE</label>
<input type="file" name="image">
</div>
<div>
<label for="blog_description">Description</label>
<textarea name="blog_description" class="text"  style="width:50%;">  </textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Post your HTML code.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer i have posted my html code as well can you please check it

Comment: still using `mysql_query`?

Comment: Make your `image` field default value `null` . I think right now it's `none` that's why its failed. one other solution is check that image is coming or not- if not save a dummy image url each time. thanks. Also don't use `mysql_*` it is deprecated use `mysqli_*` and `PDO`

Comment: Check if image is isset then insert otherwise insert empty.

Comment: @Monty can you please change in the code as iam not getting what you are saying

Comment: First use [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) function to check whether a file is uploaded or not, and then construct your `INSERT` query accordingly.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul can you please update the query as iam not getting how to do

Comment: i update my answer. pls check @user5836176

Comment: @Monty iam getting where you have updated your answer

Comment: @monty ok got i will check

Comment: @user5836176 I've given an answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul its solved thank you so much once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, start session at the very top of your PHP script, like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

And now comes your issue. First use `is_uploaded_file()` function to check whether a file is uploaded or not, and then process your form accordingly.

So your code should be like this:

```
$title=$_POST['blog_title'];
$result = str_replace(" ", "-", $title);
$description=$_POST['blog_description'];

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
    $name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $type=$_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $size=$_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $temp=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $error=$_FILES["image"]["error"];
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if($error > 0){
        die("error while uploading");
    }else{
        $permissible_extension = array("png", "jpg", "jpeg", "svg", "jpe");
        if(in_array($ext, $permissible_extension)){
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name)){
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(image,blog_title,blog_description)values('$name','$result','$description')");
                if($sql){
                    header("Location:blogimage.php");  
                    exit();
                }else{
                    echo "Insertion failed";
                }
            }else{
                echo "File couldn't be uploaded";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Invalid format";
        }
    }

}else{
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(blog_title,blog_description)values('$result','$description')");
    if($sql){
        header("Location:blogimage.php");  
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "Insertion failed";
    }
}
```

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 3):

According to your code if you are not uploading the image, value of $error becomes 4. So your if() condition is getting executed. So remove your if condition.

```html
if ($name = $_FILES["image"]["name"] != '') {
    if ($type == "image/png" || $type == "image/jpg" || $type == "image/jpeg" || $type == "image/svg" || $type == "image/jpe") {
        move_uploaded_file($temp, "upload/" . $name);
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(image,blog_title,blog_description)values('$name','$result','$description')");
        echo "upload complete";            
    }else{
        echo "File type not supported.";
    }
 session_start();
 header("Location:blogimage.php");
} else {
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(blog_title,blog_description)values('$result','$description')");
    echo "upload complete";
    session_start();
    header("Location:blogimage.php");
}
```

Comment: If i upload any zip file or pdf files it is not displaying any messages

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like below:

```
...
if($type == "image/png" || $type == "image/jpg"|| $type == "image/jpeg" || $type == "image/svg" || $type == "image/jpe" )
{
    move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name);
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(image,blog_title,blog_description)values('$name','$result','$description')");
} else {
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(blog_title,blog_description)values('$result','$description')");
}
session_start();
header("Location:blogimage.php");
...
```

Comment: still using `mysql_query`?

Comment: @Kausha Mehta it should insert if the image field is empty then that is not working for me

Comment: i will use mysqli but as of now i need solution for that image one

Comment: check if `$_FILES['file']['name']` isset or not

Answer (score 0):

I am using mysqli_query with your code, because mysql_* is deprecated:

**Modified Code:**

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "yourDb");
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

$title=$_POST['blog_title'];
$result = str_replace(" ", "-", $title);
$description=$_POST['blog_description'];

$name = "";
$failure = "";

if(isset($_FILES["image"]["name"])){
    $name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $type=$_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $size=$_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $temp=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $error=$_FILES["image"]["error"];
    if($error>0){
        $name = "";
    }
    else{
        if($type == "image/png" || $type == "image/jpg"|| $type == "image/jpeg" || $type == "image/svg" || $type == "image/jpe" )
        {
            move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name);        
        }
    }
}

$sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO blogs (image,blog_title,blog_description)
               values('$name','$result','$description')");

if($sql){
    //echo "upload complete";
    session_start();
    header("Location:blogimage.php");       
    die();
}
else{
    echo 'failure';
}

?>
```

**Explanation:**

- I am checking if if `$_FILES["image"]["name"]` is set than execute the file upload code.
- further more if `$error` is not equal to 0 use `move_uploaded_file()`
- Query will run in default either file empty or not, if empty than use `$name` as empty else use file name.

---

**From PHP Manual:**

**[mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)** -- mysqli_query — Performs a query on the database

Note that, its a procedural structure of `mysqli_*` extension, ist param of `mysqli_query` should be your connection identifier and second param should be your **MYSQL Statement**.

Comment: it is working for the image but if i give any pdf files or zip files it is accepting it should not accept any pdf or zip files erc...it should accept only images

Comment: @user5836176: accepting the other file type is related to $type: in pdf debug what value are u getting

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your fields and values dynamic :

**Try this :**

```
$_POST = array('image'=>'','blog_title'=>'yes','blog_description'=>'nothing');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value)){
        $fields .= $key.',';
        $values .= "'".$value."'".',';
    }
}
$fields = substr($fields, 0, -1);
$values = substr($values, 0, -1);
echo "INSERT INTO blogs($fields)values($values)";
```